# Stratified sampling by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sampling, fold

Creating dataframe

```
# Create a dictionary of students
students = {
    'Name': ['Lisa', 'Kate', 'Ben', 'Kim', 'Josh',
             'Alex', 'Evan', 'Greg', 'Sam', 'Ella'],
    'ID': ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006',
           '007', '008', '009', '010'],
    'Grade': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C',
              'A', 'A', 'A'],

    'Category': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
}

# Create dataframe from students dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(students)

# view the dataframe
df
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcezw.png)

Grade:
A - 50%
B - 30%
C - 20%

Category:
1 - 50%
2 - 50%

I want to get a stratified sample for this dataframe by the Grade and Category columns. For example:
[What data I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsYQs.png)

Grade:
A - 50%
B - 30%
C - 20%

Category:
1 - 50%
2 - 50%

I also tried this method:

```
df.groupby('Grade', group_keys=False).apply(lambda row: row.sample(frac=0.6))
```

But this is correct only for Grade.

And tried this:

```
df.groupby(['Grade','Category'],group_keys=False).apply(lambda row: row.sample(frac=0.6))
```

[I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXAGv.png)

Based on this article.
[Stratified Sampling in Pandas](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.e6703063-63cd8678-e84e3930-74722d776562/https/www.geeksforgeeks.org/stratified-sampling-in-pandas/)

Comment: This is random sampling. If you run it again you file find different output

Comment: some people on the list go missing in the result (ie. the list is shorter).  is this what you want ?